# nginx maximum value of server_name

Tags: nginx

I have a block of server_names which cover the [redirection](https://bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx#comment-174) of 14 domains to https

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name saim-service.com www.saim-service.com [...];
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

The block functions for the first four domains listed, then breaks down and redirects in https to that first domain listed.  `nginx version: nginx/1.8.1`  Is nginx or this version subject to limitations on the number of server_names? Is this a defect of 301 response which is then hard-wired into the browser (as a permanente redirect) and previous testing may have polluted the browser?  Is there any way to reliably overcome this problem?

Comment: I prefer to test with 302 redirect and test with curl to be sure that redirect is not cached

Comment: There is no limit on number of server names, but if you have too many of them you should increase `server_names_hash_bucket_size` and/or `server_names_hash_max_size` per http://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html. But 14 domains is really small number. Large one starts with hundreds

Comment: @AlexeyTen good suggestion about testing with 302. I have now pinpointed the failure point.  the redirect presently works with `return 302 https://$host[...]` as opposed to `server_name`.